# using multiple cookies in a web application in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

i have cookie in my web application to store user languages.
i create this cookie in

> Application_BeginRequest && Application_Start

in my global.asax file with this code :

```
Response.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Language"] = "en";
                        Response.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Direction"] = "ltr";
                        Response.Cookies["IPortalCookies"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
```

now i need to create another cookie to store likes for each user:

```
int articleid = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        //    var _ah = new ArticlesHelper();
        //    if (Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"] != null)
        //    {
        //        if (Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Likes"] == null || Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Likes"].Contains("'" + articleid + "'") == false)
        //        {
        //            if (_ah.LikeIt(articleid))
        //            {
        //                Response.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Likes"] = Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Likes"] + ",'" + articleid + "'";
        //                BindRepeater();
        //            }
        //        }
        //    }
```

but when the likes cookie is creating other cookies will disappear, and i will get this error:

```
String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: name

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: name

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: name]
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name, Boolean useUserOverride) +14174389
   PortalCore.Global.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1093
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

Comment: Which line threw this error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which line threw this error

but may i gues the below line get error

```
if (Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Likes"] == null || Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Likes"].Contains("'" + articleid + "'") == false)
        //        {
        //            if (_ah.LikeIt(articleid))
        //            {
        //                Response.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Likes"] = Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Likes"] + ",'" + articleid + "'";
        //                BindRepeater();
        //            }
        //        }
```

You need to check not equal null

```
Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Likes"] != null
```

> Before trying to get the value of a cookie, you should make sure that the cookie exists; if the cookie does not exist, you will get a NullReferenceException exception.

Comment: let me say, i wrote a portal that accepts modules,in project that i am creating module it works fine, but when i load my localhost (core portal) it shows that error. (in fact i have 2 projects 1 in visual studio other one in localhost folder)